# How to make several HTTP requests using the same session

Tags: java, http, cookies

How to make several HTTP requests in Java that will compose one session (so, share the same set of cookies etc)?

I want to authorize on one site via POST request and then make a GET request to this site with all cookies and session data.

Is it possible at all? If there is several possible ways to achieve such behavior, what is the best of them then? Synchronous calls is ok in my case btw.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sessions are usually tracked by cookies, so you'll need to collect the cookies from the Set-Cookie headers in the initial response, then pass them in Cookie headers in subsequent requests.

Comment: @blm Is it the best solution in the standard library? Should I do it manually or is there any built-in class like `CookieManager` or smth like this?

Comment: For small projects I'd just use the standard CookieManager, HttpCookie, and Http[s]UrlConnection classes. For larger projects, Apache has some libraries for handling a lot of that for you, but the standard Java classes are pretty good.

Comment: @blm Could you give me an example with `CookieManager` pls? I'll accept your answer then

Comment: I only added a comment because I don't have time to post what I'd consider a complete answer. The javadocs are pretty clear, so I'd suggest trying to get it working from the javadocs, and if you're still having problems, post the code you come up with, and what it's doing vs. what you expect and want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an http client that does this for you. E.g. Apache Commons:

https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/statemgmt.html#d5e585

If you still want to implement it yourself, have a look at [CookieHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/CookieHandler.html) and [CookieManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/CookieManager.html). Basically:

```
CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());
```

would do the trick.

Comment: Is there any way to do it via standard library? Actually I don't want to use third-party libraries in this project just for HTTP requests

Comment: You can, of course. But, believe me, sooner or later you will need pooling, authentication, caching... and you get all that for free by using a third party library. If you anyway want to implement it yourself, I have edited the answer.

Comment: @Ruben No you don't, please do *not* recommend software which is has been dead for years!

Comment: @Michael-O sorry, i posted the wrong link to the old apache httpclient. Edited.